# C++ SWIG generated code depending on Tcl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tcl, wrapper, swig

I'm using SWIG to generate a C++ wrapper around freetype. My goal is to produce a freetype DLL for WinRT with a C++ interface that will work on Windows Phone 8, however, it seems that the C++ wrapper generated depends on Tcl. Since I don't need Tcl bindings and that WinRT doesn't provide Tcl by default I was wondering if the Tcl dependencies could be turned off somehow. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to compile the generated code.

I looked up the documentations and all I found was the -tcl switch that adds Tcl bindings which seem to be by default included in the C++ wrapper generated by SWIG anyway.

I generated wrapper using the following command:
`swig -Iinclude -c++ -o freetype_cppwrap.cpp freetype_swig.i`

I'd be grateful if anyone had some pointers on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no C++ output type for SWIG (2.0.11 at least).

The `-c++` option is described as:

```
 -c++            - Enable C++ processing
```

which just means that SWIG handles C++ construct in the sources.

So what happens in your case is, that you call SWIG without any valid language selected, which falls back to the default language switch (`-tcl`).

Probably SWIG is the wrong tool for the job, some googling comes up with VC Project files for WinRT that include parts or all of freetype, maybe you can use them as inspiration.
(for example [MuPDF](https://github.com/MishaUliutin/MuPDF.WinRT/blob/master/ThirdParty/WinPhone8/libthirdparty.vcxproj))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not realise that SWIG didn't output C++, thanks for pointing that out. Shame on me for not finding that myself. I've been looking at Windows Phone 8 projects using freetype for a while now and haven't found any that used freetype from managed (C#) code. That's precisely what I want to do. I can't get the project you're linking to work. Alternatively, I haven't been able to find a SWIG alternative that would generate a C++ wrapper class from a C code. A C++ wrapper appeared to me as the easiest way to call the C functions from managed code.